# Selecting columns for plotting in R shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm building a Shiny dashboard that allows user to upload the file and, among other thing, it is plotting selected columns from the uploaded dataset. The plots I want to include are histogram, scatterplot and a line chart. For plotting I'm using plotly library.
This is the sidebar menu from ui.R where I ask the user to upload the file

```
sidebarMenu(

        fileInput("file", "Upload your file"),
        menuItem("Upload options", tabName = "options", icon = icon("upload"),
                 menuSubItem(radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                                          choices = c("Comma" = ",", "Tab" = "\t", "Space" = " ", "Semicolon" = ";"))),
                 menuSubItem(radioButtons("nas", "Handle missing values", 
                                          choices = c("Omit rows with NAs", "Replace with mean", "Replace with median"))),
                 menuSubItem(checkboxInput("header", "Header", value = TRUE)))
```

Here's the dashboard body from ui.R

```
dashboardBody(
      tabItems(

        tabItem(tabName = "summary", verbatimTextOutput("struct")),




        tabItem(tabName = "spread", dataTableOutput("table")),

        tabItem(tabName = "viz",
                fluidRow(
                  box(title = "Histogram", plotlyOutput("histogram", height = 250)),
                  box(title = "Line chart"),
                  box(title = "Scatterplot"),
                  box(title = "Column selection", uiOutput("inputwidget"))


                )),

        tabItem(tabName = "about", tableOutput("contents"))








      )
```

Here's the data handling part of server.R

```
data <- reactive({

    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){
      return()
      } else if(tools::file_ext(file1) == "csv") {
        read.csv(file = file1$datapath, 
                   sep = input$sep, 
                   header = input$header, 
                   skipNul = TRUE)
      } else if (tools::file_ext(file1) == "xlsx"){
        readxl::read_excel(path = file1$datapath)
      }
  })

  columns <- reactive({
    names(data())
  })
```

and here is the part where I want to create the actual histogram

```
 output$inputwidget <- renderUI({
    selectInput("col", "Select the column", choices = columns())
  })

  output$histogram <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(data = data(), x=~data()[input$col], type = "histogram")
  })
```

When I run the app, uiOutput and renderUI don't seem to be working. I don't get the dropdown menu with all the columns as I expected. I tried different solutions for renderPlotly({}), some of those included get() function and I got various different errors. Sometimes it was: "Invalid first argument", other times it was: "Object of type closure is not subsettable" and so on. I can't write all examples because I really don't remember what did I try exactly everytime. 
I searched for answers, but non of those helped me because they all either use in-built datasets such as iris, mtcars or trees, or they have a deeper specific problem that I don't have time to get into.

Also, when I want to autocomplete input$col it's not recognized, so there's another potential problem?

I'm guessing my problem comes from data handling part on server.R, but I'm stuck.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: What do you get with `data()[[input$col]]` instead of [] in `output$histogram <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(data = data(), x=~data()[input$col], type = "histogram")
  })` ?

Comment: I get this: 
"attempt to select less than one element in get1index" for a split second and then it disappears

Comment: Then you need to go into debug mode. Use `browser()` to execute step by step and `cat ( str( data() ) )` or `message( str( data() ) )` to know your data structure.